# How to run Jupyter notebooks locally with password and no token?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter

Since update, `jupyter notebook` command will run jupyter with a token, by default. So that you have to open a URL like `http://localhost:8889/?token=46b110632ds2f..`.

It is not very inconvenient, since you need to copy-paste this token from terminal. How can I run a jupyter server with a predefined password, so that I can save it in my browser and don't need to copy-paste the token from the command line?

Answer (score 7):

You can from the command line run:

`jupyter notebook password`

The command prompt will ask you for the password and then set the hash in a JSON document in your configuration directory.

You can determine that with:

`jupyter --config-dir`

If you delete the file, the password will no longer work.
You may wish to set up SSL as well.

Comment: I got this error: `No such file or directory: /Users/volodymyrk/password`

Comment: Same for me. Running jupyter 4.3.0 from fresh anaconda install.

Comment: This means your 'jupyter notebook' application is not started and tries to start while looking for password file, which is not there. You can check my answer with more information of custom config and more control.

Comment: Make sure to either run `jupyter` once or simply run `jupyter notebook --generate-config` before attempting to set a password. Otherwise it complains that it cannot find the config file, which I assume does not exist before the first run.

Answer (score 2):

You can make a configuration to all option in a file, generated by command `jupyter notebook --generate-config`. This will produce a file with all configuration explained and commented out in folder ~/.jupyter/jupyter_notebook_config.py .

In this file you can un-comment

```
## Allow password to be changed at login for the notebook server.
#
#  While loggin in with a token, the notebook server UI will give the opportunity
#  to the user to enter a new password at the same time that will replace the
#  token login mechanism.
#
#  This can be set to false to prevent changing password from the UI/API.
c.NotebookApp.allow_password_change = True
```

and set some starting or no with token.

```
## Token used for authenticating first-time connections to the server.
#
#  When no password is enabled, the default is to generate a new, random token.
#
#  Setting to an empty string disables authentication altogether, which is NOT
#  RECOMMENDED.
c.NotebookApp.token = ''
```

Answer (score 2):

`$ jupyter notebook --port 5000 --no-browser --ip='*' --NotebookApp.token='' --NotebookApp.password=''`

this will give the following warnings. understand the risk.

[W 09:04:50.273 NotebookApp] WARNING: The notebook server is listening on all IP addresses and not using encryption. This is not recommended.

[W 09:04:50.274 NotebookApp] WARNING: The notebook server is listening on all IP addresses and not using authentication. This is highly insecure and not recommended.